# success message on redirected page asp .net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

here i am going to redirect , and i want show some massage on new page which is open when it redirect ,
how i show this massage

i am on Editinv.cshtml page and after click on  submit button it will be redirect to Detail.Cshtml page and ther i want to show success massage

my redirect code jsonResul

```
 return Json(new
        {
            redirectUrl = Url.Action("Details", "Perchus" ,new { id }),
            isRedirect = true
        });
```

and this is pust method

```
$.post(url, { Id: mid, PerTranCode: mtran, Srno: msr, ProductId: mProductId, PGstRate: mPGstRate, PerchesQty: mPerchesQty, PerchesRate: mPerchesRate, GstTax_Amount: mGstTax_Amount, Total: mTotal, ProductName: mProductName, ProductGstCode: mProductGstCode, PreCode: PreCode }, function (json) {
            //mtran: mtran, msr: msr, mProductId: mProductId, mPGstRate: mPGstRate, mPerchesQty: mPerchesQty, mPerchesRate: mPerchesRate, mGstTax_Amount: mGstTax_Amount, mTotal: mTotal, mProductName; mProductName
            if (json.isRedirect) {
                window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;

            }
        });
```

please help me .

Comment: first please check if the $.post have recived the answer with console.log(json), and check if your action c# recive the petition. 
Later change it, you should specify it will be json answer 
   $.post(url, {params}, "json").done(json){ console.log(json) }

Answer (score 0):

You can add message to query string by changing to

```
redirectUrl = Url.Action("Details", "Perchus", new {id = id, message = "Edited Success"})
```

redirectUrl will be `/Perchus/Details/1?message=Edited Success`

and in your Detail.Cshtml add code to display message

```
<p>@Request["message"]</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hien Nguyen